# What is the best practices to do LINQ query when it comes to the context of async, await, task with IEnumerable & IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, async-await

This is the IQueryable object that I wrote for one of my APIs. It just join with some of the schemas and returns company data. (I am using .net 6 for the project)

the query which return IQueryable object

```
    private IQueryable<CompanyDto> FetchAllComnpay()
    {
        return from com in _context.Companies
               join cty in _context.Cities on com.CityId equals cty.Id
               join con in _context.Countries on cty.CountryId equals con.Id
               join lc in _context.Currencies on com.LocalCurrencyId equals lc.Id
               into slc
               from sublc in slc.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join ic in _context.Currencies on com.InterNationalCurrencyId equals ic.Id
               into sic
               from subic in sic.DefaultIfEmpty()

               select new CompanyDto
               {
                   Id = com.Id,
                   CompanyName = com.CompanyName,
                   CompanyCode = com.CompanyCode,
                   CountryId = cty.CountryId,
                   CountryName = con.CountryName,
                   CityId = cty.Id,
                   CityName = cty.CityName,
                   MobileNo = com.MobileNo,
                   PhoneNo = com.PhoneNo,
                   Email = com.Email,
                   Web = com.Web,
                   ZipCode = com.ZipCode,
                   Address = com.Address,
                   CreatedBy = com.CreatedBy,
                   CreatedDate = com.CreatedDate,
                   UpdatedBy = com.UpdatedBy,
                   LastUpdatedDate = com.LastUpdatedDate ?? null,
                   LocalCurrencyId = com.LocalCurrencyId ?? 0,
                   LocalCurrencyName = sublc.CurrencyName ?? "",
                   InterNationalCurrencyId = com.InterNationalCurrencyId ?? 0,
                   InterNationalCurrencyName = subic.CurrencyName ?? "",
               };
            }
```

**Then I fetch a list of companies like this**

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<CompanyDto>> GetAllCompanies()
    {
        return await FetchAllComnpay().AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }
```

**Then fetch a single company the like this**

```
    public async Task<CompanyDto> GetCompayByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await FetchAllComnpay().Where(e => e.Id == id).AsNoTracking().FirstAsync();
    }
```

Actually, I am forced to work with .Net core in my org. That's why I am asking this.

Here's the point that I wanted to know regarding this context

- Am I on the right track
- if I m not what are the best available best practices that I can apply in this type of query
- Will you kindly provide me with any suggestions, please?

Comment: 1) Yes. 3) joins can be removed if you have navigation properties, `AsNoTracking` is not needed if you have `Select`.  EF Core do  not track custom entities.

Comment: 1. I didn't user navigation properties (although they're nice)  because I wanted to  Parent and Child to be two separate aggregate roots. I wanted them to be able to talk to each other via foreign key not through infrastructure-specific Entity Framework navigation properties.


2. according to the documentation of Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) it is saying to use AsNotracking() when it comes to read-only scenario.

Comment: Do not use `AsNoTracking` if you project to DTO, it has no sense.

Comment: Using navigation properties does not preclude you from using aggregate roots, nor are they in any way infrastructure-specific.  What they would give you is much shorter, cleaner and easier-to-read Linq.

Answer (score 1):

> - Am I on the right track

Yes, you are.

> - If I m not what are the best available best practices that I can apply in this type of query?
> - Will you kindly provide me with any suggestions, please?

Here we deal with specific issues (there is an error, it takes too long, etc.).

For "any suggestion" https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ will be better.